# Control Bluetooth latency

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

Is there a way I can increase the latency to my Bluetooth speaker? I am playing music synchronously using SoundWire on some other devices. The BlueTooth speaker is ahead of the other devices so if I could increase the latency it would sync playback.